What is the closest thing to Python multiprocessing's Pool.imap when the iterator only works on the main thread?
Suppose I have an iterator that only works on the main thread (throws an exception otherwise), but I still want to distribute work (one task per item from the iterator) over several processes. (Because the cost of the work per item is much higher than the cost of the iteration.)
How can I modify the (toy) program below to distribute the work over several processes,  without modifying Graph or GraphIterator or get_number_from_graph, and using only standard Python libraries?
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, num_vertices):
        self._num_vertices = num_vertices

class GraphIterator:
    def __init__(self, num_graphs):
        self._num_graphs = num_graphs
        self._current_graph = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        assert threading.current_thread() is threading.main_thread(), 'iterator only works on the main thread'
        if self._current_graph < self._num_graphs:
            self._current_graph += 1
            return Graph(self._current_graph)
        else:
            raise StopIteration

def get_number_from_graph(graph):
    return graph._num_vertices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_graphs = 100
    print('Sequential result:', sum(get_number_from_graph(g) for g in GraphIterator(num_graphs)))
    print('Parallel result: ', end='')
    result = 0
    with Pool(processes=None) as pool:
        for t in pool.imap(get_number_from_graph, GraphIterator(num_graphs)):
            result += t
    print(result)

Current output:
Sequential result: 5050
Parallel result: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rburing/src/gcaops/multiprocessing_issue.py", line 33, in <module>
    for t in pool.imap(get_number_from_graph, GraphIterator(num_graphs)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 873, in next
    raise value
AssertionError: iterator only works on the main thread

Desired output:
Sequential result: 5050
Parallel result: 5050


Why do you have this artificial "main thread" constraint? What is its purpose?

@SIGHUP In reality the iterator reads from a SQLite database using a "global" connection object, and it doesn't work on other threads. I could approach the problem in other ways (which could be the subject of other questions), but here I'd like to know how it can be solved in this particular way (which seems possible but not exactly trivial).

Your iterator isn't being called from a different thread, the problem is that your test for being in the main thread is failing for some reason (some interaction between threading & multiprocessing, I think).  threading.get_ident() == threading.main_thread().ident might be a more reliable test.

@jasonharper See my comment above (posted a few seconds before yours). In my real situation I get a ProgrammingError from SQLite3, so I'm not in control of how the test looks, I just know I'm getting an exception. Also, that alternative test doesn't prevent the AssertionError.

@jasonharper: pool.imap does, in fact, consume the iterator in another thread. Specifically, the pool's internal _task_handler thread. It does this so the pool can keep distributing tasks to workers while the main thread does arbitrary other work.

Specifically for this particular case, it might be okay to just pass check_same_thread=False to the original sqlite3.connect call. This would disable the same-thread check, but you'd have to take responsibility for ensuring that threads don't try to use the same connection at the same time, and there might be other dangers I'm not familiar with.

@user2357112 Thanks, indeed that's exactly what I was trying to avoid with this question :-)

Run the iterator in a normal for loop, and use the apply_async pool method instead of one of the map variants: that way you control the iterator in the current thread. There could be some boiler plate for retrieving the results, so it might be even better to use concurrent.futures.ProcessPollExecutor and the .submit method instead.

ProcessPoll imap will indeed run the iterator in another thread -
Run the iterator in a normal for loop, and use the apply_async pool method instead of one of the map variants: that way you control the iterator in the current thread. There could be some boiler plate for retrieving the results, so it might be even better to use concurrent.futures.ProcessPollExecutor and the .submit method instead, and then concurrent.futures.as_completed to retrieve the results without the need for a callback:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_graphs = 100
    print('Sequential result:', sum(get_number_from_graph(g) for g in GraphIterator(num_graphs)))
    print('Parallel result: ', end='')
    result = 0
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(get_number_from_graph, item) for item in GraphIterator(num_graphs)}
        result = sum(fut.result() for result in as_completed(futures))


If you need the results in order or otherwise to know which inut generated which output, this will need some modifications - but simply associating each future with a sequential number, and then returning that number along with the result allows one to build a dictionary instead:
...

def enumerator(func):
    def wrapper(item_number, *args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return item_number, result
    return wrapper

@enumerator
def get_number_from_graph(graph):
    return graph._num_vertices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_graphs = 100
    ...
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(get_number_from_graph, index, item) for index, item in enumerate(GraphIterator(num_graphs))}
        result = dict(fut.result() for result in as_completed(futures))




Thanks a lot for your answer! Is there any way to avoid building the entire set of futures at once, which I assume Pool.imap would have avoided? In my real application the analog of num_graphs (the number of items coming out of the iterator) can be quite huge.

yes, through regular coding - just use a while loop  encompassing controlled .submit and  and next(as_completed(futures)) calls, adding a bit more state variables to keep a tab on how many tasks you want to build and see running at once. You may find concurrent.futures.wait more convenient than as_completed, as well.
If you search for other answers of mine containing concurrent.futures, I probably have gone through that pattern a couple of times.

Also, if you want your main thread to go about doing other things while it "awaits"  for some of the off-process results to get ready before submitting new tasks, this is a pattern that will fit  well  with asynchronous programming in an asyncio loop. The loop.run_in_executor method of asyncio loops is a more idiomatic call than executor.submit i this context.
